# Close Sheet with signal from C++ in Blackberry Cascades

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-cascades

I have a UI for some decryption software that gets invoked from the mail client on an encrypted attachment.

My decryption object emits a signal on successful completion of the decryption :

```
emit decryptedChanged();
```

which I pass through my controller object (attached as _encryptedattachmentencryptedattachment to the QML UI:

```
connect(m_decryptor, SIGNAL(decryptedChanged()), this, SIGNAL(decryptedChanged()));
```

I have a Sheet which is shown on invocation on an encrypted file: when the UI is initialised:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    splashscreen.open();
}
```

(at the end of my TabbedPane, before the attachedObjects where the Sheet is.)

I am trying to get the Sheet to close based on the signal.

```
Sheet {
            id: splashscreen
            peekEnabled: false
            Page {

                Container {
                    layout: DockLayout {
                    }
                    ImageView {
                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill

                        imageSource: "asset:///images/background.png"
                    }

                    Label {
                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                        text: "Decrypting..."
                        multiline: true
                    }
                }
            }
            onCreationCompleted: {
                _encryptedattachment.decryptedChanged.connect(splashscreen.onDecryptedChanged());
            }
            function onDecryptedChanged () {
                splashscreen.close();
            }
        }
```

The splashscreen will not close. I know the object can be seen by the UI, as I use other properties etc. Am I missing a QPROPERTY or something?

**Update:**

This is my signal definition:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void decryptedChanged();
```

**Update again:**

I have added some console.logs to the QML:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    _encryptedattachment.decryptedChanged.connect( splashscreen.onDecryptedChanged() );
    console.log("connected");
}
function onDecryptedChanged() {
    console.log("closing");
    splashscreen.close();
}
```

This gives me the following ouptut:

```
closing
connected
```

which is backwards, and the splashscreen does not close.

Comment: It does not seem like any of the code you have linked is responsible for this not working. Are you certain your signal is being emited?

Comment: Yes, I added a debug print just before the emit, and it printed. Could it have something to do with the order in which things happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
 _encryptedattachment.decryptedChanged.connect( splashscreen.onDecryptedChanged() );
```

the parentheses after the onDecryptedChanged mean that that function is called, not connected to.

```
 _encryptedattachment.decryptedChanged.connect( splashscreen.onDecryptedChanged );
```

works fine.

Comment: I once spent 2 hours debugging something similar!